# How can I find out the root cause of SIGTRAP core dump of GDB

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gdb, coredump

My app is randomly (once a day) crashed and I have tried several ways to find out the reason but no luck.
With other core dump or segmentation fault cases, I can locate where does it happen by gdb, but for this case, gdb don't give me too much hint.
I need some advice for my continuous debugging, please help.

**GDB output when my app crashed**

```
    [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
    Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
    Core was generated by `/home/greystone/myapp/myapp'.
    Program terminated with signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
    #0  0x00007f5d3a435afb in g_logv () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
    [Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f5cea3d4700 (LWP 14353))]
    (gdb) bt full
    #0  0x00007f5d3a435afb in g_logv () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
    No symbol table info available.
    #1  0x00007f5d3a435c6f in g_log () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
    No symbol table info available.
    #2  0x00007f5d3a472742 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
    No symbol table info available.
    #3  0x00007f5d3a42cab3 in g_main_context_new () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
    No symbol table info available.
    #4  0x00007f5d3f4894c9 in QEventDispatcherGlibPrivate::QEventDispatcherGlibPrivate(_GMainContext*) () from /opt/Qt5.9.2/5.9.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
    No symbol table info available.
    #5  0x00007f5d3f4895a1 in QEventDispatcherGlib::QEventDispatcherGlib(QObject*) () from /opt/Qt5.9.2/5.9.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
    No symbol table info available.
    #6  0x00007f5d3f266870 in ?? () from /opt/Qt5.9.2/5.9.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
    No symbol table info available.
    #7  0x00007f5d3f267758 in ?? () from /opt/Qt5.9.2/5.9.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
    No symbol table info available.
    #8  0x00007f5d3efa76ba in start_thread (arg=0x7f5cea3d4700) at pthread_create.c:333
    __res = 
    pd = 0x7f5cea3d4700
    now = 
    unwind_buf = {cancel_jmp_buf = {{jmp_buf = {140037043603200, 4399946704104667801, 0, 140033278038543, 8388608, 140037073195984, -4344262468029171047, -4344357617020880231}, mask_was_saved = 0}}, 
      priv = {pad = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, data = {prev = 0x0, cleanup = 0x0, canceltype = 0}}}
    not_first_call = 
    pagesize_m1 = 
    sp = 
    freesize = 
    __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "start_thread"
    #9  0x00007f5d3e43c41d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:109
    No locals.
```

**Solutions I have tried**

- Search topic related with SIGTRAP
  - People said it is in debug mode and there are somewhere in the code set break point. However, my app is compiled in release mode without break point.
- Catch signal handler and ignore SIGTRAP
  - No success, I can only ignore SIGTRAP sent by "kill -5 pid". With the SIGTRAP occurs randomly in runtime, my app is still crashed
- Fix memory leak in code
  - Initialize pointer with nullptr
  - Double check mysql C API race conditions
  - Double check delete array action and double check assign value for the index out of array boundaries
- Check signals and slots
  - My app is built on Qt frameworks as a GUI application, there are many signals and slots I have checked but no ideas how are they related to SIGTRAP core dump.
- Check exceptions for opencv
  - I use opencv for image processing tasks. I have checked for exception cases
- Shared memory
  - Memory shared between main process and sub processes were carefully checked

**Example code**
A lot of code in my app, but because gdb don't give me exactly where does it happen, so I don't know which code I should share. If you need it for checking for suggestion, please tell me which part of the code you would like to check. My app have these following parts.

- Mysql in C api mysql 5.7.29
- User interface (alot) by Qt framework 5.9.2
- Image processing with opencv 2.4.9
- Process flow in multi threading by Qt framework 5.9.2

If there is any ideas, please share me some keywords then I could search about it and apply to my app. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> for this case, gdb don't give me too much hint

GDB tells you *exactly* what happened, you just didn't understand it.

What's happening is that some code in `libglib` called `g_logv(..., G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL, ...)`, which eventually calls  `_g_log_abort()`, which executes `int3` (debug breakpoint) instruction.

You should be able to `(gdb) x/i 0x00007f5d3a435afb` and *see* that instruction.

It looks like `g_main_context_new()` may have failed to allocate memory.

In any case, you should look in the application `stderr` logs for the *reason* `libglib` is terminating your program (effectively, `libglib` calls an equivalent of `abort`, because some precondition has failed).

Comment: You are right that I'm not fully understand gdb output. Library libglib is used by libqtcore, which my source code doesn't call it directly. 
This is the output of ```(gdb) x/i 0x00007f5d3a435afb
=> 0x7f5d3a435afb <g_logv+683>: jmpq   0x7f5d3a435a57 <g_logv+519>
```
This time, stderr logs saved in /var/sys/log show a warning
```[91781.798205] traps: ProcessCenter[14353] trap int3 ip:7f5d3a435afb sp:7f5cea3d38b0 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.2[7f5d3a3e5000+10f000]
```
Thanks for your suggestion, I will try to find out why the g_main_context_new cannot alloc new memory